# Memory leaks when loading images to scroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a scrollView in which i load images into from the net .I sometimes get memory warnings, which i assume are because i am doing something wrong with the images loader.
I am trying to fix little things, and i just wanted to show the code here, and hear maybe there are more things i can fix to get rid of this warnings.

So every time the scroller (iPad) has only 4/5 images that are : `current page-3->current page+3`.

This is how i load the images(every image has also a blur effect with Apple's classes) :
(should i allocated imageView every time? can i improve something here? )

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
                   {
                       NSData *imdata2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                        {
                            UIImage *theImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imdata2 scale:1];
                            UIImage *LightImage = [theImage applyLightEffect];


                           UIImage *scaledImage =[resizer resizeImageToWidth:[Globals sharedGlobals].imagesWidth WithImage:theImage];

                          CGRect viewSizeBack=CGRectMake(scroller.bounds.size.width*toPage , 0, scroller.bounds.size.width, scroller.bounds.size.height);

                          int x=[Globals sharedGlobals].pageMargins;
                          int y=([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-scaledImage.size.height)/2;


                          CGRect viewSizeFront=CGRectMake(x , y, scaledImage.size.width,scaledImage.size.height);




                          UIImageView *backImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewSizeBack];
                          UIImageView *frontImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewSizeFront];



                          backImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
                          backImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                          backImageView.image=LightImage;

                          frontImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
                          frontImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                          frontImageView.image=scaledImage;
                          frontImageView.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
                          frontImageView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0 blue:255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

                          [backImageView addSubview:frontImageView];

                          backImageView.tag=toPage;
                          frontImageView.tag=toPage;
                          [scroller addSubview:backImageView];


                        });
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only ever have 3 images loaded at a maximum - the previous page (if it exists), the current page and the next page.

Any other images you have loaded above this is wasteful because you can't see them and they're just taking up memory for no good reason. If the images aren't too big then you can maintain them in memory and purge them when you get a warning, but for large images this will still generally cause you issues.

Comment: This is not entirely true because when user is scrolling fast enough he will get to pages that still does not have an image, and see a white space- which is for my opinion is a bad UI .. so when i give it 6 images, i can scroll pretty fast and always have content in my scroller . don't you think ?

Comment: It's a trade off, if you have the memory available then sure, enable fast scrolling, but we're talking about memory constrained devices and fast scrolling is usually an edge case so taking additional memory for everyone when only a few will 'benefit' is counter productive. It is really a benefit too? Can you usefully see the image while fast scrolling...

Comment: Yea.. i think you right, i have tried now to set it to 3 images, but i still get this memory warning- its happens at the moment i am scrolling- and i think they have to do with the Async loading.. is there a way to find the exact problem ?

Comment: Breakpoint in the warning method and see what each thread is doing. Use instruments and snapshot during scrolling each 'page'.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use ARC then add this:

```
[backImageView autorelease];
[frontImageView autorelease];
```